# Create Custom Invite Link in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a bot that has command where it will create a **custom invite link** for a server but it isn't working.

This is my current code:

```
       @custominvite_group.command(name="new", description="Create a new custom invite link")
       @app_commands.describe(name="The new invite link's name")
       async def newci(interaction: Interaction, name: str):
           if len(name) > 25:
               await interaction.response.send_message("The new invite name is too large", ephemeral=True)
               return
           if interaction.guild.premium_tier < 3:
               await interaction.response.send_message("This server does not have enough boosts for a custom invite link", ephemeral=True)
               return
           try:
               current_invite = await interaction.guild.vanity_invite()
               if current_invite != None:
                   await invite[0].delete()
               new_invite = await interaction.guild.create_invite(max_age=0, max_uses=0, unique=True, reason="Creating a new invite link", target_type=discord.InviteTarget.embedded_application, target_application_id=None, target_user_id=None, target_user_type=None, target_user=None)
               await new_invite.edit(reason="Changing the invite link name", code=name
               await interaction.response.send_message(f"New Invite Link: {new_invite}") 
           except: 
               await interaction.response.send_message("Invite link already in use.", ephemeral=True)
```

It outputs the error `'Guild' object has no attribute 'create_invite'`

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation, you'll see that the [Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#guild) object doesn't have a `create_invite` method. If you want to change a server's custom invite (what is called `vanity invite`) you should use the [Guild.edit()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.edit) method and inform the `vanity_code` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found this out a few minutes before your replied and I was gonna answer my own question. I didn't think that to change the guild's vanity URL you would have to use guild.edit() which is very dumb and I should've probably known that so mb for that.